# boot loader cant load windows 8 after installing ubuntu. boot repair even didn't work out

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, windows-8

I had my windows 8 OS.just yesterday i wanted to dual boot with ubuntu 14.10. And installed it in a another drive(other than C:\). But after installing ubuntu, boot loader directly loaded to ubuntu(with out giving a option to windows 8 on start up).
I tried "boot-repair".And now on start up, it only gives option

1.ubuntu*
2.Advance options for ubuntu

but it doesn't load to windows 8.
Please help. As soon as possible.
And even i cant see my datas in hard drive through ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 possible outcomes/scenarios from this.

1: When inside ubuntu try running `sudo update-grub` in the terminal. To find the terminal search `terminal` in the Dash, located in the top left corner. This will locate all existing OS's and add them to the Grub menu loader.

2: If that does not fix your issue, you most likely, accidentally, erased your Windows 8, and replaced it with Ubuntu.